# django application selenium testing no static files

Tags: python, django, selenium

I want to do some functional tests on my django app. I'm using selenium, tests works but the problem is with static files. The css/js status is not found.
My tests is running on localhost:8081.
Example bootstrap.css:

```
<h1>Not Found</h1><p>The requested URL /static/frontend/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.css was not found on this server.</p>
```

I can't find any information do I have add some extra config for selenium app?

Trackback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/home/t/py/django/bid/src/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1028, in __call__
    return super(FSFilesHandler, self).__call__(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/t/py/django/bid/src/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/t/py/django/bid/src/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1011, in get_response
    return self.serve(request)
  File "/home/t/py/django/bid/src/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1023, in serve
    return serve(request, final_rel_path, document_root=self.get_base_dir())
  File "/home/t/py/django/bid/src/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/static.py", line 50, in serve
    fullpath = os.path.join(document_root, newpath)
  File "/home/t/py/django/bid/src/venv/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 77, in join
    elif path == '' or path.endswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Instead of using [LiveServerTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#liveservertestcase) from `django.test` you can use 
[StaticLiveServerTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.testing.StaticLiveServerTestCase) from `django.contrib.staticfiles.testing`.

Notice not just the different class-name, but also the different module-name:

```
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase
#     ^-- vs --v
from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase
```

Comment: Lifesaver. All the selenium doco I found is for django 1.6.

Answer (score 9):

Ok I found the solution. First I had to add in setting

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'my static dir'
```

then:

```
./manage.py collectstatic
```

Comment: Thank you, `LiveServerTestCase` uses production settings (`DEBUG = True`) and therefore needs staticfiles to be collected first. It's clear now

Comment: @MartinM Should that be `DEBUG = False`?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and none of the answers above helped me.

For anyone using [Whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/)  as a static file server,  it turns out you may have to change the value of the `STATICFILES_STORAGE` setting in your app, from:

```py
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"
```

To:

```py
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage"
```

That fixed my problem. See [this page](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#add-compression-and-caching-support) for more information.

Comment: Thank you SO much for this answer! I would have spent countless hours on this.

I really wonder what causes this issue though.